# Can't create a PPPoE connection on Fedora 15

Tags: pppoe, fedora-15

I've just installed Fedora 15 (with KDE) and I'm having problems creating a PPPoE connection.

First I tried using the NetworkManager.But if I create a DSL connection, it doesn't appear in the Network widget, so that I can connect to it. I've checked the option to connect at startup, and then did a reboot, but again, there was no connection.

After this I tried using pppoe-setup from Konsole. I followed all the steps, and in the end it had created the connection. The ppp0 interface was up and it had ip's assigned. I checked the connection status, and it said that the link was up, but there was no traffic in or out.

I'm pretty sure that I entered the data correctly. I've managed to configure this in Ubuntu many times with no problems.

I checked the Fedora forums and there were some people that reported similar behavior, but no one had responded to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somebody forgot to include pppo3 package in the release version. It was in the alpha version though. Find the package in the CD and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Well at first, I too faced a similar problem and resolved it like this: I didn't use the system tray icon on the left that shows a computer icon for the network. It had no ADSL option. I am using Fedora Scientific with Plasma KDE. I then went to the Start icon>applications>Administration>system settings>network>Connections. Here I didnt do anything in the connections name. I just clicked an + sign in the connections list and added an ADSL. There, I left the service name blank but gave the used name and password. Very soon my network was up and running and have been using it supercool for a year now!!!